# How to trigger an oozie workflow job with Bamboo?

Tags: oozie, bamboo, cloudera-cdh

I am new to bamboo. I know in general how to trigger an oozie workflow job in CDH env. Could someone please suggest some good documentation which describes this?

In Bamboo I have just created a plan which does the code build pointing to my repository each time I check in. Now I need to know - how can I trigger a workflow job from bamboo?

I understand that this should be some kind of command which needs to trigger from bamboo to execute. Please, suggest

Answer (score 0):

You could use oozie command line interface from script execution step.

1. Install oozie client on the machine with Bamboo (or on any other and ssh it). On CDH cluster machines it should be preinstalled.
2. Create bamboo script task (Details: [Bamboo Script](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Script))
3. Run start job command in script task, e.g. `oozie job -oozie http://localhost:8080/oozie -start 14-20090525161321-oozie-joe`. See details on cli usage [here](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.1.3-incubating/DG_CommandLineTool.html#Starting_a_Workflow_Coordinator_or_Bundle_Job)